# How to write a program to display "too big result" when a very big calculation is involved?

Tags: python

I tried calculating 32**(32**32) in a graphical calculator, but the program hanged. How to display "too big result" like string instead of hanging?
I used the following function.

```
def result(text):
    global backend, frontend, backend_list, frontend_list
    try:
        backend_list.append(str(eval(backend)))
        backend=backend_list[-1]
        frontend_list.append(str(round(eval(backend),5)))
        frontend=frontend_list[-1]
        backend_list.clear()
        backend_list.append(backend)
        frontend_list.clear()
        frontend_list.append(frontend)
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert(INSERT, frontend)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        backend=frontend=""
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert(INSERT, "not defined")
    except TypeError:
        backend=frontend=""
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert(INSERT, "type error: presumably\ncomplex number or\nmissing operators")
    except:
        text.delete(1.0, END)
        text.insert(INSERT, "error")
```

Comment: what is the point of showing such a large number. It cannot be even stored in a variable

Comment: what is your actual objective?  You want to write this result to file?

Comment: btw, that is a ridiculously large number.  It's not a surprise your graphing calculator died

Comment: In usual calculators, when the user types 32^32^32... It simply shows 'calculation outside accepted range' or something similar... I want to display something like that

Comment: The problem is that Python doesn't have a fixed limit on the size of its integers. The only way to know that it's too much is if it fills up memory trying to calculate it.

Comment: you're doing the calculation in the main thread, so it cant keep updating the UI at the same time. Solution would be to do the calculation in another thread/process, and if the other thread is taking too long, you can display something like "please wait" or just kill the thread and show "too big result" without waiting further

Comment: What is the rule that you will use to decide whether the number is too large, without calculating it?

Comment: I actually think this is an interesting problem.  How would you get the leading digits and exponent (base 10) of that number, printed to file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with python doing this is that python doesn't technically have a size limit for integers. Eventually your computer will run out of memory trying to calculate this, but it'll take a while and the computer will hang until it does.

Floating-point numbers have a size limitation, unlike integers. You could, if you wanted, convert your arguments to floats and rely on the built-in float behaviors to do your job for you:

```
try:
    eval('float(32) ** 32 ** 32')
except OverflowError:
    print("Result too large")
```

The problem with *that* is that you're relying on `eval()`, which gives you no control. If you want your calculator to be truly flexible, you'll have to decode and interpret the expression yourself. [`ast`, or 'Abstract Syntax Tree'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), is the best method for this, and you can use the combination of `ast.parse(your_input)` and `ast.walk(result_of_parse)` to go through the operands one by one and evaluate them as necessary. This will be complicated, and you'll need to carefully think through how to implement it, but one simple solution could just be to go through the tree and convert all constants to floats, if they aren't already:

```
import ast

...

def eval_ast(expr='32 ** 32 ** 32'):
    # decompose into parsed elements
    # if entered normally, expr() will be a hierarchy of AST objects. The top few
    # are not useful to us:
    #    ast.Module     (has attribute .body containing a list of the next level)
    #    ast.Expr       (has attribute .value containing the next level)
    # so we attempt to ignore them.
    expr_obj = ast.Expression(ast.parse(expr).body[0].value)
    # walk through the nodes in the AST and convert integers to floats
    for node in ast.walk(expr_obj):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Constant):
            node.value = float(node.value)
    # recompose back into an evaluatable expression
    expr_eval = ast.fix_missing_locations(expr_obj)
    exe = compile(expr_eval, filename="<string>", mode="eval")
    return eval(exe)
```

This will, as written, throw a "Result too large" error. If called with a different expression, that would not overflow, it will correctly return a result:

```
>>> eval_ast('32 ** 32 ** 32')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
>>> eval_ast('2 ** 32')
4294967296.0
```

You can customize this and integrate it into your calculator as needed. It might be more useful to you to manually walk through the AST expression and evaluate each step yourself, if you need more precision or granular control.